# Errors when attempting to run c++ program compiled in Netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans

I have for the last couple of hours been trying to set up a cronjob for a C++ application I developed in Netbeans. I am programming on a Windows machine and using a Ubuntu server as a build host. It sets it up so a file is put into a distribution folder and I assume that it's the one I have to execute. I execute it using the following command line:

```
g++ program
```

After that it pops up with the following errors:

```
testproject: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.text+0x0):
first defined here
testproject: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.fini+0x0):
first defined here
testproject:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4
+0x0): first defined here
testproject: In function `__data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.data+0x0):
first defined here
testproject: In function `__data_start':
(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
testproject: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.init+0x0):
first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/crtend.o:(.dtors+0x0): multiple definition of
`__DTOR_END__'
testproject:(.dtors+0x8): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in testproject(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be cre
ated.
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However when I click run in Netbeans it runs just fine. Which command do I need to run in order to make this work correctly?

Comment: `g++` isn't used to run the program, just compile. Once it's compiled, just run it as `program` (or possibly `./program`).

Comment: Awesome. That worked. I need the ./ Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`g++` is a [compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler). It turns your source code into a program you can run directly. This is unlike Java, which runs on a separate program called a [virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine).

So for a `C++` program you have written, you would do

```
g++ my_source.cpp -o my_program
./my_program
```

The first line compiles your code into a run-able program (this step is often more complicated, with multiple source files, and separate programs to manage the build process, such as [`make`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29)). You only have to do this step once (and again if you ever change the program). This part will probably be hidden from you if you use an IDE (such as NetBeans).

The second line runs the new program (assuming the first step all went well). The `./` just means "run it in this directory" (without it, your system would go off and look for the program in a few specific places).